# I am trying to compare two Tuples

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

I am trying to write a function to compare tuples of similar type.

```
def compareTuples(tuple1: (String, String, Int), tuple2: (String, String, Int)): (String, String, Int) = {
   // if tuple1.Int < tuple2.Int return tuple1 else tuple2.
}
```

How do I access the third element or the int in each tuple?

Thanks

Comment: this should explain everything you need to know http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_tuples.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access a value in a tuple `t`, you can use `t._1`, `t._2`, etc.

For you that would then result in

```
def compareTuples(tuple1: (String, String, Int), tuple2: (String, String, Int)): (String, String, Int) = {
   if (tuple1._3 < tuple2._3) tuple1 else tuple2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this use case more generic, you can add a `maxBy` method to `Tuple` (of any size, but here we'll use `Tuple3`):

```
implicit class Tuple3Comparable[T1, T2, T3](t: (T1, T2, T3)) {
    type R = (T1, T2, T3)
    def maxBy[B](other: R)(f: R => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): R = if(ord.lt(f(t), f(other))) other else t
}
```

Then you can make comparisons such as:

```
("z", "b", 3).maxBy(("c", "d", 10)) (_._3 ) // selects the second one, ("c", "d", 10)
("z", "b", 3).maxBy(("c", "d", 10)) (_._1 ) // selects the first one, ("z", "b", 3)
```